# T-SQL Contains not working for values with point as 2nd or 3rd symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

There is a SQL statement, generated by stored procedure, looking like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM UInstitutions as UI
WHERE Contains(UI.Name, @ParamName)
```

It seems that if value has dot (`.`) as second or third symbol, it's unsearchable, when searching by exact match or substring. E.g.:

```
[dbo].[FindRecords] N'b.la bla'
```

or

```
[dbo].[FindRecords] N'bl.a bla'
```

return **nothing**, while

```
[dbo].[FindRecords] N'bla. bla'
```

returns

```
Id Name
--------------
1388 b.la bla
1389 bl.a bla
1386 bla bla
1390 bla. bla
```

What could be the reason for this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per MSDN for the Contains statement:

> Punctuation is ignored. Therefore, CONTAINS(testing, "computer failure") matches a row with the value, "Where is my computer? Failure to find it would be expensive." For more information on word-breaker behavior, see Configure and Manage Word Breakers and Stemmers for Search.

[CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

Also see: [Configure and Manage Word Breakers and Stemmers for Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, `sys.dm_fts_parser` from that article is quite interesting, will explore it futher.

Comment: If this answer resolved your issue or put you on the right track for, please don't forget to accept. Thanks! : )

Comment: Of course, I will accept it, if I'll manage to solve the problem with the help of the articles you linked. I just can't work on this problem now, will return to it a little later. So for now just upvoted it, as this info is valuable to know anyway.